# What service is using 127.0.0.2 on Win7?

Tags: loopback

I have been setting up servers on a virtual machine and using a dynamic dns service to access them. Now, when I access them, for example with ping, from the host machine, Win7 resolves the address to 127.0.0.2.
The address also resolves to 127.0.0.2 with the virtual machine disabled.
My hosts file shows no entry for 127.0.0.2. 
I need to find out what is using that loopback addy and why. Any clues?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is 127.0.0.2 IP address for?](http://superuser.com/q/393700/52365)

Answer (score 0):

any address in the range 127.0.0.1 to 127.255.255.255 is mapped to localhost.

everything in the 127 range is always a loopback

Comment: Yes. I understand that. My question though, is what has created the loopback address of 127.0.0.2.  How do I get rid of it, for example?

Comment: you can't that's the point. it will always resolve all the time on every computer

Comment: meaning you can always ping it. that doesn't mean it is serving something

Comment: it's build into the IP protocol datagram

Comment: _on every computer_ is a bit misleading: http://superuser.com/questions/458875/how-do-you-get-loopback-addresses-other-than-127-0-0-1-to-work-on-os-x

Comment: ok your right, on ever WINDOWS computer. if you want to configure the kernel use a unix or bsd system

Comment: I do not want to get rid of the loop back address. I want to know what is using it.  Until yesterday I had never seen 127.0.0.2. . If localhost uses 127.0.0.1, what is using 127.0.0.2?

Comment: they both are. at the same time

Comment: localhost, 0.0.0.0, and 127.* are the same thing

Comment: to test it, if you have a server running, like a rails server, go to any address in the 127 range, they will all serve the same thing

Comment: TheRealMrCrowley, thanks for teaching me about loopback addys. I  think part of my problem in stating my issue is that I have been using IP and domain interchangeably, which probably has not helped. So I will state my prob again, this way.  If I ping a domain on the cloud, google.com, for instance, it resolves to 58.162.62.40. When I ping my own domain, it resolves to 127.0.0.2.  Before yesterday this did not happen. Having said that, maybe I should do a system restore.

Comment: @grasshopper that is way overkill.  the default loopback ip on ping should have no affect on whatever you're running.  I wouldn't recommend doing a system restore over it. did anything break from seeing the .2 instead of .1?

Comment: and yes domain resolution is much different than the loopback protocol range

Comment: For some reason the issue has now resolved itself.  When I ping the domain, win7 resolves it to the domain address instead of .2., just like it did before yesterday. I am still in the dark, but I do want to thank all who took time to help.